# How can I load a large gif image into imageview Android?

Tags: android, android-glide

Currently, the gif image is being read using Glide version 3.6.1
But there is a problem. When i load a gif between 300MB and 400MB, the image is not visible but only the black screen appears.

```
Glide.with(this).load(strConvertPath).asGif().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).into(imgView);
```

Comment: This is a ridiculously large image. Keep in mind it will be even several times bigger when expanded to memory for display. Actually I am surprised, you did not get an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: glide would load gif as whole, so it would take time to parse 300mb gif, so i would advice against it, you should make this gif a mp4 and load as a video and play it in loop this way it could buffer and play loaded content